# Upgrading Ubuntu(32 bit) 10.10 -> 11.04 fails and causes a kernel panic on boot

Tags: upgrade

On Ubuntu 10.10 machine Upgrade to Ubuntu 11.04 using the update manager. The upgrade fails and leaves the system in an unstable state. When I reboot the system I get a kernel panic on boot. The error points to /opt/abc/runtime/lib/libc.so.6.

By researching on this I found that there is a third party software abc causes problem. It has it's own runtime(libc) library. In /lib/ directory there is a link file /lib/ld-abc.so.2 --->/opt/abc/runtime/lib/ld-linux.so.2.

If we rename this file to /lib/abc.so.2 or remove this file the the upgrade is success.

Here is the upgrade log of where it crashes(apt-term.log)

=====

```
Services restarted successfully.

Processing triggers for libc-bin ...

ldconfig deferred processing now taking place

/usr/bin/dpkg: /opt/abc/runtime/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by /usr/bin/dpkg)

/usr/bin/dpkg: /opt/abc/runtime/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.8' not found (required by /lib/libselinux.so.1)
```

=====

Could you please let me know what would be the problem of having a run time link library file in /lib directory. Does the ubuntu upgrade check the 3rd part runtime as well?

Answer (score 1):

By providing a link on /lib to a 3rd party libc, you are causing the dynamic linker to use the 3rd party libc instead of the system library, for all binaries that need libc. You should not do it, it could have broken your system but not allow to launch any system binaries.

If you need a specific application to use it's own library versions, create a script and use the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable like this:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/abc/lib
/opt/abc/bin/run
```

Comment: Thanks **João Pinto** for quick reply. This answer is really useful. The dinamic linker should use the "/lib/ld-linux.so.2 -> ld-2.11.1.so" file as system runtime, it should not use "/lib/ld-abc.so.2 --->/opt/abc/runtime/lib/ld-linux.so.2". Does ubuntu upgrade looks for all the runtime in /lib directory and create problem. Since i am not getting any problem during running the third party binary which has the runtime in /lib. I get only problem during upgrade ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Because of Unity the older versions of Ubuntu(10.10 and lower) can't upgrade seamlessly to Ubuntu 11.04 or 11.10.

I recommend you to back-up your important data and make a fresh install...